# How do you insert value that I have def in SQLite using python 2.7?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to create sqlite database from the value I have given in python but having trouble finding which input I need to put. I figure out how to input simple text but not value I have given to. For example I want to record value of HAPPY

```
Happy = ("Please HELP")

from sqlite3 import *

connection = connect(database = "top_ten.db")


topten = connection.cursor()

topten.execute("DELETE FROM Top_Ten")

topten.execute("INSERT INTO Top_Ten VALUES ('1',**HAPPY**)")


connection.commit()
topten.close()
connection.close()
```

What input do I have to give so that python recognize HAPPY as given value not text? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try [parameters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3):

```
topten.execute("INSERT INTO Top_Ten VALUES ('1',?)",(Happy,))
```

don't forget adding the comma after **Happy** because it should be a tuple